# Server files within Netbeans

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, netbeans, xampp

I currently trying to get AJAX working in NetBeans with a php file like the one shown on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297535/how-to-display-ajax-in-html?noredirect=1#comment35666693_23297535).

I have now figured out I have to put my php file into a server folder. How do I go about doing that?

I'm currently using XAMPP within NetBeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far i understand your question, you are trying to find the xampp server directory path. If yes, then look for htdocs folder inside xampp installation directory. For example if you have installed your xampp in D://xampp then you have to put your php file inside D://xampp/htdocs/

Hope it helps.